# Firebase Emulator Seems To Be Trying To Run TypeScript Code As JavaScript Code In Sign In With Google PopUp In Remix

Tags: firebase-authentication, firebase-tools

I am building a sign in page with firebase auth. I have made a simple button that you can click to login or signup with Google. It works fine when using it without the firebase emulator, but when I use the firebase emulator I don't see any of the accounts I have made in the emulator UI and nothing happens when I click the button to make the account in the UI when I click the button. I opened dev tools on the popup and I see this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'.

I went to the sources panel and saw that it was a error on the error part of a try catch block. This is the line of code that has the error: `} catch (e: any) {`. It seems to be trying to run TypeScript code as JavaScript code. Any idea why and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been bothering me for days. A quick fix I found was to install a previous version of firebase tools:

```
npm install -g firebase-tools@9.23.0
```

Then run `firebase init` again, but only to re-download the emulators.

You should see the following to indicate success:

```
...
i  database: downloading firebase-database-emulator-v4.7.2.jar...
...
i  database: Removing outdated emulator files: firebase-database-emulator-v4.7.3.jar
...
```